# Tense forms of "Have to have"

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I say something like such, I mean are they all right?

> I will have to have some lessons.
>
> I have to have some lessons.
>
> I had to have some lessons.

Comment: [say something like this or like that. not like such.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those examples are all valid.

However, I personally avoid using multiple senses of “have” in the same sentence because that may be confusing. You can usually ([but not always](https://www.speakconfidentenglish.com/have-to-need-to-must/)) replace “have to” with “need to”:

- I will need to have some lessons.
- I need to have some lessons.
- I needed to have some lessons.

Once you do that, “to have” doesn’t really add anything, so you can remove it:

- I will need some lessons.
- I need some lessons.
- I needed some lessons.

This becomes even more important for clarity once you get to other tenses that use “have” as a helper:

- I will have needed some lessons.
- I have needed some lessons.
- I had needed some lessons.
- Having needed some lessons, ...
- If I had needed some lessons, ...

While “If I had had to have some lessons, ...” would be technically valid, it takes more mental effort to both read and write that correctly, whereas the “had needed” version is clear on the first try.

In the present tense only, you could also replace “have to” or “need to” with “must”:

- I must have some lessons.

Comment: I disagree vehemently with the idea that OP should "avoid" the kind of repetition that occurs in his examples. Apart from anything else, in ***real*** (spoken) language, they're not even "the same" word - the first instance would normally be enunciated as ***haff / hat*** rather than ***have / had***, because in the minds of most native speakers *they're not even the same word anyway.*. But native speakers are perfectly happy even with usages like *You need **to** learn **to** drive **to** get a food delivery job*. It's only *learners* who are bothered by such things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m a native speaker and it bothers *me* to read or write that. I agree that I might do it in informal speech, though.

Comment: It's nothing to do with "informal" speech! Check out [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+*+had+had+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10), showing that apart from general-purpose pronouns (*he, we, she*, etc.), the most common proper nouns  in *If XXX had had to [do something]* are in fact ***Horace*** and ***Rembrandt***. Ancient Roman poets and classical painters are the stuff of academia, not "informal speech / casual conversation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Point taken; I’ve softened it to my personal preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Native speakers are not like some mysterious aliens from some unknown world with a strange taste in language . "You need to learn to drive to get a food delivery job" bothers everyone, native, non-native, anyone.

Comment: I can say that I _have to have_ my hair cut, or a tooth extracted, or a Covid test, and do not feel any awkwardness whatsoever.

Comment: @CoderInNetwork That doesn't bother me one bit. You need to learn to sing to get a place in a choir to prove to Papa how musical you are.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey to to to doesn’t bother me the way had had does.

Comment: In speech **I / we / they had had** generally becomes **I'd / we'd / they'd had**, as in **we'd had a hard time with had hads**, which is much less bothersome.

Comment: @StephenS - I do find lots of repetitions of 'and' tiresome.

Comment: @StephenS - I've retracted my closevote (will think about maybe switching to an *upvote* if and when I read the rest of the answer text! :) I've no patience with the idea that English "should" be influenced by factors that might make it "easier" for non-Anglophones to learn, but I will defend to the death the right of every *native* speaker to express themselves however they like (so long as the people they're addressing can understand the intended meaning).

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: That's a bizarre assertion which I would say is definitely *not* true for most Anglophones. In fact, I'd go further and say I'd be prepared to bet that if anyone did (or even, *has done*) the relevant research, to the extent that *some* people seriously dislike such repetitions, that position would tend to be more likely among the less articulate / less highly-educated. Nothing personal, obviously - just *statistically*.

Comment: ...I've decided *not* to upvote, because of *You can usually replace “have to” with “need to”*. That's true at a crude level, but I don't think learners should be told to just use "need" all the time (especially if it's to resolve a "non-issue"), because [***need, have to** and **must** are all slightly different.*](https://www.speakconfidentenglish.com/have-to-need-to-must/)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I agree they aren’t exactly the same (synonyms rarely are), hence the weasel words. I’m not trying to dumb things down for learners; I do the same myself.

Comment: Arguably I'm being a bit harsh by withholding my upvote here. I can certainly see that there's no good reason your answer should go into any great *detail* about those ***need, have to, must*** differences. Not that I want to bully you into making changes, but if you would just add parenthetical *(but not **always**)* after *"**usually**"* (perhaps with a link to the page in my previous comment, or something similar), I would unhesitatingly upvote.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Edited.

Comment: @StephenS - Upvoted :)